# How do I make exceptions to a global ignore in SVN using SmartSVN?

Tags: svn, version-control, smartsvn

How do I make an exception to a global ignore in SVN using SmartSVN?

I do not wish to remove and then re-apply the ignore. Is there a way of adding a single file that is caught by the ignore?

**Example scenario:**

My global ignore file includes ".pdf".

How can I commit my file "MoriohRadio.pdf" to the repository without removing the global ignore.?

Comment: Don't know about SmartSVN but with CLI, you can just `svn add MoriohRadio.pdf` even if PDF files are ignored. If it's a one-off, you can just do that.

Comment: @Friedrich thanks, I was expecting to be able to find some kind of similar add command in SmartSVN but have been unable. Thanks for your answer in any case.

Comment: @Friedrich Your comment helped me to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve this, you need to first show ignored files. This can be done by clicking the "show ignored files" icon in the top right side of the screen:

[image: "show ignored files" button]

Then you can right click the file you want to commit to SVN then click add.